# Magento2 - Can we use deprecated payment method on live website?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, braintree

I recently have upgraded from `Magento 2.3.3 to 2.3.6` and `Braintree` payment method has been deprecated in 2.3.6.

Can we use deprecated payment method on live website in `Magento2` ?
Is there any bad consequence using deprecated payment method. ?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use deprecated methods, unless they're removed. But it isn't the best of practises as methods are typically deprecated for a reason. Always best to use the most uptown date methods.

I'd advise to check why the methods were deprecated via the release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,ofcourse,You are able to use it. I also used Braintree(Depracated) in one of live website.

please accept solution so someone can find best answer.